# Can't reasonably complete a low quality question review

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

I looked in the low quality review queue (there was a 1 on it).  Turned out to be a question.

[image]

That is certainly not a looks good.  I've already added a comment *before* it hit the queue (and have the only comment there at all).  Its not an edit I can save.  And [I've used all my close votes for the day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCcUY.png).

The only possible answer is skip.  If this is the case, I don't believe I should have seen the review in the first place.

Given that:

- I already commented on the question
- have no close votes

These two criteria should have the question not show up in the review queue because there is no action I could reasonably take.

You might say that 'Edit' is an action, but I believe that the fact that I've previously seen (and commented on) the question means that I don't have any idea of an edit to make to fix it.

(Aside: I am curious if it would have hit my low quality review queue if I had previously cast a close vote on it)

Yes, I know this is not the easiest thing to reproduce, but its there and can be reproduced in the right circumstances.

Comment: Perhaps the Close button should change to a Recommend Close button when you're out of close votes, and simulate the flagging dialog... If not, it would seem that questions shouldn't be shown to users who are out of close votes for the day.

Comment: For now, skip. Someone else will pick it up for you.

Comment: "*I believe that the fact that I've previously seen (and commented on) the question means that I don't have any idea of an edit to make to fix it.*" -- I don't think `commented on bad post without edit -> don't know how to edit bad post` is a safe implication to assume in the general case. I'd argue that editing is a difficult and free-form enough task (compared to voting) that you may *be able* to do it in some case, but sometimes feel *unwilling* to undertake the task.

Comment: @Bart that is what I did... its just a "there is a situation here that is problematically detectable and should take into account if I can do the review" - just as if every question in the close review queue is one I've already cast a down vote on, it doesn't show those to me.

Comment: @MichaelT Sure. No argument there.

Comment: @animuson for me, if I choose to flag because I'm out and choose "it doesn't belong here", I'm told I'm out of close votes.

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's because normally, if you have the close privilege, that flag option takes you to the close dialog. It would have to *not* do that in this particular case, which might not be feasible. But I'd rather a close flag go to the queue, rather than forcing a moderator to make a unilateral decision on a custom flag just because a user is out of close votes.

Comment: Argh, when a question starts with "Hi fellow programmers", the OP's account should be automatically destroyed when they click "Post Your Question"

Comment: @animuson it sounds like all you're suggesting here is that it be put into the close review queue, perhaps there should just be a button for "Migrate to Close queue" instead.

Comment: @Jimmy Well flagging for closure would automatically add it to that queue, if using the system-provided canonical reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you should be performing a certain action but are no longer able to perform that action (i.e. out of votes, close votes, delete votes, etc.), then you can either skip the post, or you may consider simply stopping reviewing until you again are able to perform that action.

Since, in this case, only *one* of the valid options for the review isn't available to you (voting to close, due to being out of votes), but not *all* of the review options (editing, or looks good) the review system can't *know* that there aren't any actions that you can take.  The review system doesn't know that the post shouldn't be edited, or that it doesn't look good.  Do you think that you shouldn't be show a perfectly good post that you would want to "looks good" just because you're out of close votes?  That would be proposing that you shouldn't be able to review content if *any* of the options are unavailable, rather than *all* of the options being unavailable.

Comment: I assure you, I've already downvoted it.  Downvoting isn't an option to complete the review.  Flagging isn't an option either.  I am out of close votes (that the system should have detected before offering that as an option).  Low quality *answer* reviews are ones that I can do.  And I do have sufficient rep (11k on P.SE) to do close votes.